# Make SQL Select Query Read Only

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to set an "Select Only" Mode?

I work with SQL Server Management Studio and im afraid of editing some lines while selecting stuff from the database!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are called user permissions. So you need to set the account you have only select rights to the database.

So

```
DENY insert ON all TO user
DENY update ON all TO user
DENY delete ON all TO user
```

Comment: Just for clarity: it's not possible to set this on a per-connection basis (unlike some other database engines). So you can't use your 'sa' login but switch it to read-only mode, for example.

Answer (score 3):

create a new user with select only permissions. then use that user to connect.

Answer (score 3):

ALTER DATABASE database-name SET READ_ONLY

http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/SQLReadOnly.aspx